# .htaccess redirection is not working for url with arguments

Tags: .htaccess

I want to redirct my site url to new site

```
http://www.oldsite.com/user/profile/?type_id=1
```

To

```
http://www.newsite.com/newuser/profile_one
```

I have fixed URLs to be redicted using `.htaccess`

code for `.htaceess` is as below

**Edited code**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
RewriteEngine On
#http://www.oldsite.com/user/profile/?type_id=1
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} type_id=1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^user/profile/$ http://www.newsite.com/newuser/profile_one$1? [R=301,L]
```

This is working fine but for the value `type_id 1 to 10` it selects 1 only and from `type_id 20 to 29` it takes 2 record...

So I am preety much sure that it is reading first number only

Comment: @faa if type_id=1 or type_id=10 or type_id=11 to 19 .. it goes for 1 only...I want it to have difference for 1 and 10/11/12/13...etc

Answer (score 1):

I am giving my answer as

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} type_id=1$ [NC]
```

We have to add `$` when query string ends.